# How can I import a file using React.js, ES6 and Webpack based on the value of a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have a React.js component called `CountryFlag`. I also have a directory of SVG images for each country's flag at `countries/`

This component takes a single prop - `countryCode`. This would be something such as `ES` for Spain.

How can I use the ES6 `import` construct with `this.props.countryCode` when `this.props` is not in scope?

I have tried to do this in `componentDidMount()` but get a syntax error:

```
Syntax error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (6:2)
```

Comment: You wouldn't do this, you just reference their url and host the images on a CDN

Comment: You can't import something based on a property (as far as I know). Would something like this help? : https://github.com/matthewwithanm/react-inlinesvg  you could import the Isvg module in the component, then have the Isvg src as the property value `<Isvg src={this.props.svgImage}/>`

Comment: @CallumLinington: I will be doing but I'm bundling it for production and need to do this using Webpack.

Comment: @Jayce444: Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `System.import` to `import` a component dynamically in `componentDidMount`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = { component: null }
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadComponent(component => this.setState({ component }));
}
loadComponent = callback => {
    let component = null;
    // This needs to be relative to the current module otherwise Webpack won't know where to look
    System.import(`./countries/${this.props.countryCode}`).then(module => callback(component = module))
    return component;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Will this allow Webpack to bundle the SVG?

Comment: Why exactly import and not require? The former will result in a new chunk, which may or may not be the desirable behaviour.

Comment: Well I am not sure, but it should help you bundle the svg as well. You can try and see.

Comment: [System.import is deprecated](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-import/#system-import-is-deprecated) and has been replaced with `import()` (the function)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `require`. like:

```
class Whatever extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.countryImage = null;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { countryCode } = this.props;
    this.countryImage = require(`./countries/${countryCode}.svg`); 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <img src={this.countryImage} alt="Whatever" />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use your props on src to your image.
Something like
`<img src={"./img/" + this.props.country + ".svg"}>`

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent Webpack from bundling the SVG though?

Comment: Really not sure, but i hadn't problems with this. Just with write right path to images)